# How to make a ghost mouse or "secondary mouse" with python or whatever

Tags: python, windows, automation, mouse, pyautogui

I have a script on python that emulates mouse click depending on certain images on the screen, using pyautogui. My question is, is there a way to click the image without actually using the mouse ?

Comment: Do you control the target window? Doe it process WM_ mouse messages?

Comment: idk im pretty new to it, how can do I know if it process WM_ mouse messages ?